# DataMember's name

Tags: .net, wcf, datamember

Is it possible somehow to add `DataContract`/`DataMember` attributes for existing binary classes (available only as compiled dll)? The main goal is to set `DataMember` name, to avoid ugly property names for generated proxies. I think, I am looking for something like [metadata classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) in WCF RIA services, but maybe there is some better approach. Thanks!

P.S. IL modification is not an option.

Comment: No, I don't think so - you need to have the source to be able to add `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes

Answer (score 0):

In the end all the attributes are no more than a bit of metadata used to generate the WSDL and scheme. If you look at workflow services you will not find an interface with a ServiceContract  and methonds with OperationContract but the same kind of WSDL is still generated by the WCF infrastructure. The same should be possible with a regular WCF service.

I have never done so but [this blog post](http://www.dolittle.com/blogs/einar/archive/2008/02/01/programatically-creating-a-wcf-contract-and-exposing-it-part1.aspx) about programatically creating a WCF contract should point you in the right direction.